# PDF page manipulation, from 2 page per sheet to one page per sheet automatically

Tags: pdf, preview, automation

I have a PDF with following pattern:

[image]

I need to transform **automatically** each page of this PDF into two distinct pages, as follows:

[image]

and

[image]

So, if I had a PDF with 12 pages (2 slides for each page) I will expect a new PDF with 24 pages (1 slide for each page).

How do I can do that?

**Please note that**: this question is quite similar to [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/272893/pdf-page-manipulation-from-2-page-per-sheet-to-one-page-per-sheet) (yet correctly answered) but with a difference: this operation should be automated. How to do that very quickly with huge PDFs?

Comment: There is a [similar question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48912/how-to-print-an-image-across-two-pages). You might want to try [poster printing ability of Reader](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6855527?start=0&tstart=0). There also is [illustrated how-to](http://macintoshhowto.com/printing/how-to-print-across-multiple-pages-or-make-a-banner-in-osx.html).

Comment: I had already seen the Acrobat option. But it has a serious problem: it requires the use of the PRO version which is paid in order to save the PDF file. I am looking for a workaoround, but I have not found anything at the moment. I am continuing to look for. Thank you!

Comment: If you do not mind dealing with command line tools, [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/192293/282638) (and the whole thread) might be of interest to you. While tools mentioned in the thread (like [poster](https://schrfr.github.io/poster/) or [poppler](https://poppler.freedesktop.org)) are not part of macOS, they can be easily installed with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/).
[Another solution](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206468/split-tile-a3-landscape-pdf-to-a4-portrait) suggests [pdfposter](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdftools.pdfposter) `pip install pdftools.pdfposter`.